# How is the value NULL?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I am getting query results that determine if user story hasn't been changed (changedate) in the last one day.

[image: query]

I'm following [this article](https://www.azuredevopsguide.com/automated-email-reminders-for-workitems-in-azure-devops/) to build the logic app as the intention is similar

For some reason, despite the query returning a valid response (at least 1 user story result), the foreach expression is throwing this error:

```
ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'For_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['value']' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.
```

How is it NULL when clearly there is a user story returned?

[image: editor]

Get query results:

**OUTPUTS:**

```
[
  {
    "System.Id": 12345,
    "System.WorkItemType": "User Story",
    "System.State": "New",
    "System.Title": "Experiment"
  }
]
```

***Parse JSON:***

**Inputs:**

**Content:**

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "System.Id": 12345,
      "System.WorkItemType": "User Story",
      "System.State": "New",
      "System.Title": "Experiment"
    }
  ],
  "@odata.nextLink": null
}
```

**Schema**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "body": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "value": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "System.AssignedTo": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "System.Id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "System.State": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "System.Tags": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "System.Title": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "System.WorkItemType": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "System.Id",
              "System.WorkItemType",
              "System.State",
              "System.AssignedTo",
              "System.Title"
            ]
          }
        },
        "@odata.nextLink": {}
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Cache-Control": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Content-Length": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Content-Type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Date": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Expires": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Pragma": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Set-Cookie": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Strict-Transport-Security": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Transfer-Encoding": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Vary": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "X-Content-Type-Options": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "X-Frame-Options": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "x-ms-request-id": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "statusCode": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "System.Id": 12345,
      "System.WorkItemType": "User Story",
      "System.State": "New",
      "System.Title": "Experiment"
    }
  ],
  "@odata.nextLink": null
}
```

Comment: Just try dragging in the body without the `[‘value’]` … that’s my tip.

Comment: @Skin Gives me error and wont let me save it `The template validation failed: 'Unable to process template language expressions for action 'For_each' at line '1' and column '390': Expected an expression, but found string literal 'body('Parse_JSON')?['body']' instead.'.` The error actually makes sense. we should be looping on the value here not the body. The value is an array of user stories as seen in screenshot

Comment: Can you provide the JSON in your question as text? Screenshots are no good for us to recreate. Also, why are you using Parse JSON? Why not just loop off the back of the returned results from the Get Query Results step?

Comment: @Skin Ive updated the post with parse json inputs/outputs samples. but i also tried the get query results value instead of the parse json value and it worked! Ive posted an answer based on that, but honestly since im new to logic apps i was following that article i linked which was using parse json, idk why, i simply followed their steps too. Still, why is it thinking its null for the parse json?

Comment: No worries man, glad that suggestion worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Value from the Get Query Results directly works.

[image: get query results]